# How to remove number character from string in c#

Tags: c#, .net

i have a string like string `st ="12,34,56,345,12,45"` and i want remove number 34 from this string i did like `string newst = st.replace(",34","");` but it is removing 34 from 345 , how to prevent this
**EDIT**
34 can be anywhere,here i am generating dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
var oldString = "34,12,34,56,345,12,45,34";
var newString = String.Join(",", oldString.Split(',').Where(x => x != "34"));
```

We split on `','`, use LINQ to exclude `"34"`, then join the string back together by `','`.

Comment: Correct one,LINQ is so powerful and less code

Answer (score 3):

It's very simple:

```
var st ="12,34,56,345,12,45";
var newst = st.replace(",34,", ",");
```

If it can be anywhere, you may use [the regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

```
var input = "34,234,35,36,34,37,345,34";
var pattern = @",?\b34\b,?";
var regex = new Regex(pattern);
var result = regex.Replace(input, ",").Trim(',');
```

Shorter notation could look like this:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(input, @",?\b34\b,?", ",").Trim(',');
```

**Explanation of the regular expression:** `,?\b34\b,?` matches the word `34`, but only if preceded and followed by word-delimiter characters (because of the word boundary metacharacter `\b`), and it can be (but doesn't have to be) preceded and followed by the comma thanks to `,?` which means none or more comma(s).

At the end we need to remove possible commas from the beginning and end of the string, that's why there's `Trim(',')` on the result.

But I would say @crashmstr's solution is better than trying to tune the regular expression for this particular use case.

Comment: 34 can be anywhere

Comment: Don't *have* to use regular expressions, you can use LINQ too.

Comment: @crashmstr OK, thanks.

Comment: I don't think this is quite right. In the example where 34 falls in the middle, we need to replace with a `,`. Only on the borders do we replace with an empty string.

Comment: @JoshC. It can be replaced by the comma always and finally you can just trim them.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
string newst = st.replace(",34,",",");
```

Granted this only works if the number you want to replace is between two commas. If you want something more advanced, use `Regex.Replace()`

Here's an example:

string temp = Regex.Replace("12,34,56,345,12,45", @"^34,", "");
string newst = Regex.Replace(temp, @"34$,", "");

You could also use `String.TrimStart` and `.TrimEnd` to clean up the borders.

Also, I like crashmstr's example.

Comment: Assuming `34` is not at the beginning or end.

Comment: but if 34 is last number then? comma does not come for that

Comment: it can be anywhere

Comment: @peter I have updated my answer to show how you can trim the edges.

Answer (score 1):

split and work in list:

```
string[] arr = st.Split(',');
List<string> list = arr.ToList();
list.Remove("34");
```

or regex:

```
var replaced = Regex.Replace(st, @"\b34\b[,]","");
```